# Extrusion in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

Is there any way to extrude gluPartialDisk in OpenGL - have been looking around
but cant seem to find one.  If there isn't any way is there something similar I can 
look at.

Comment: What do you mean by "extrude"? I.e. modify the geometry somehow before rendering? Like Blender's Extude option?

Comment: I want to add thickness to the partial disk

Comment: So you basically want to procedurally generate some geometry (an array of vertices) and render it i.e. using `glDrawArrays`. This can be done with a little maths and geometry; but are you sure you won't want to simply design this cup in Blender, save as a file and then load and render it in your app?

Comment: I cant use Blender in this case as it is for an assignment so I will just have to figure out the vertices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function in OpenGL to do this (note: gluPartialDisk is not an OpenGL function. It's a GLU function, which is not part of OpenGL itself). So if you want to do extrusion, you'll have to compute the vertices yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I have tried drawing the vertices myself but I cant quite get there - can you give me the pseudo code to do it - I get stuck on the inner and outer curves and how to render them.  I am trying to draw the handle of a cup

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this one it contains code to draw partial cylinder.

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/145831-Source-code-for-partial-cylinder